# Cannot prevent wildfly from creating log file

Tags: java, logging, wildfly

Wildfy keeps creating log files even though I removed file logger from standalone.xml
Wildfly runs in docker, don't know if it is relevant to the problem...

Below is my standalone logging sub system:

```
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="JsonFormatter"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
                <custom-handler name="SENTRY" class="someClassName" module="moduleName">
                    <level name="ERROR"/>
                    <formatter>
                        <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                    </formatter>
                    <filter-spec value="not(match(&quot;(duplicate key value violates unique constraint)\\s.(idx_segment_uuid|idx_passenger_uuid|idx_item_uuid|pk_booking_number_lookup)&quot;))"/>
                </custom-handler>
        <file-handler name="AUDITREADFILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="AUDITPATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="audit_read.log"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.hibernate.SQL">
            <level name="INFO"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="com.hazelcast">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="someClassName">
            <level name="INFO"/>
                handlers>
                    <handler name="SENTRY"/>
                </handlers>
                    </logger>
        <logger category="someClassName">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="someClassName">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="com.vsct.oce.services">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="audit.read" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="AUDITREADFILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="JsonFormatter">
            <custom-formatter module="moduleName" class="someClassName">
                <properties>
                    <property name="version" value="1.0" />
                    <property name="facility" value="java-test" />
                    <property name="fields" value="Time,Severity,ThreadName,SourceClassName,SourceMethodName,SourceSimpleClassName,LoggerName,NDC" />
                    <property name="extractStackTrace" value="true" />
                    <property name="filterStackTrace" value="true" />
                    <property name="mdcProfiling" value="true" />
                    <property name="timestampPattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" />
                    <property name="mdcFields" value="Time,Severity,ThreadName,SourceClassName,SourceMethodName,SourceSimpleClassName,LoggerName,NDC" />
                    <property name="dynamicMdcFields" value="mdc.*,(mdc|MDC)fields" />
                    <property name="includeFullMdc" value="true" />
                </properties>
                    </custom-formatter>
            </formatter>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="AUDITPATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

Generated logging.properties:

```
# logging subsystem has been defined in the XML configuration.





# Additional loggers to configure (the root logger is always configured)

loggers=org.hibernate.SQL,audit.read,com.arjuna,com.company,com.company.className,com.hazelcast,com.vsct.oce.services,com.company.someClassName,sun.rmi,jacorb,org.jboss.as.config,jacorb.config,org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler



logger.level=INFO

logger.handlers=CONSOLE



logger.org.hibernate.SQL.level=INFO

logger.org.hibernate.SQL.useParentHandlers=true



logger.audit.read.level=INFO

logger.audit.read.useParentHandlers=false

logger.audit.read.handlers=AUDITREADFILE



logger.com.arjuna.level=WARN

logger.com.arjuna.useParentHandlers=true



logger.com.company.level=INFO

logger.com.company.useParentHandlers=true

logger.com.company.handlers=SENTRY



logger.com.company.someClassName.level=ERROR

logger.com.company.someClassName.useParentHandlers=true



logger.com.hazelcast.level=WARN

logger.com.hazelcast.useParentHandlers=true



logger.com.vsct.oce.services.level=DEBUG

logger.com.vsct.oce.services.useParentHandlers=true



logger.com.company.someClassName.level=ERROR

logger.com.company.someClassName.useParentHandlers=true



logger.sun.rmi.level=WARN

logger.sun.rmi.useParentHandlers=true



logger.jacorb.level=WARN

logger.jacorb.useParentHandlers=true



logger.org.jboss.as.config.level=DEBUG

logger.org.jboss.as.config.useParentHandlers=true



logger.jacorb.config.level=ERROR

logger.jacorb.config.useParentHandlers=true



logger.org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.level=WARN

logger.org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.useParentHandlers=true



handler.AUDITREADFILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler

handler.AUDITREADFILE.level=ALL

handler.AUDITREADFILE.formatter=AUDITPATTERN

handler.AUDITREADFILE.properties=append,autoFlush,enabled,fileName

handler.AUDITREADFILE.append=true

handler.AUDITREADFILE.autoFlush=true

handler.AUDITREADFILE.enabled=true

handler.AUDITREADFILE.fileName=/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log/audit_read.log



handler.CONSOLE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.ConsoleHandler

handler.CONSOLE.level=INFO

handler.CONSOLE.formatter=JsonFormatter

handler.CONSOLE.properties=autoFlush,target,enabled

handler.CONSOLE.autoFlush=true

handler.CONSOLE.target=SYSTEM_OUT

handler.CONSOLE.enabled=true



handler.SENTRY=com.company.someClassName

handler.SENTRY.module=com.company.module

handler.SENTRY.level=ERROR

handler.SENTRY.filter=not(match("(duplicate key value violates unique constraint)\\\\s.(idx_segment_uuid|idx_passenger_uuid|idx_item_uuid|pk_booking_number_lookup)"))

handler.SENTRY.formatter=PATTERN



# Additional formatters to configure

formatters=COLOR-PATTERN





formatter.JsonFormatter=com.company.someClassName

formatter.JsonFormatter.module=com.company.module

formatter.JsonFormatter.properties=version,facility,fields,extractStackTrace,filterStackTrace,mdcProfiling,timestampPattern,mdcFields,dynamicMdcFields,includeFullMdc

formatter.JsonFormatter.version=1.0

formatter.JsonFormatter.facility=java-test

formatter.JsonFormatter.fields=Time,Severity,ThreadName,SourceClassName,SourceMethodName,SourceSimpleClassName,LoggerName,NDC

formatter.JsonFormatter.extractStackTrace=true

formatter.JsonFormatter.filterStackTrace=true

formatter.JsonFormatter.mdcProfiling=true

formatter.JsonFormatter.timestampPattern=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH\:mm\:ss.SSSZ

formatter.JsonFormatter.mdcFields=Time,Severity,ThreadName,SourceClassName,SourceMethodName,SourceSimpleClassName,LoggerName,NDC

formatter.JsonFormatter.dynamicMdcFields=mdc.*,(mdc|MDC)fields

formatter.JsonFormatter.includeFullMdc=true



formatter.AUDITPATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter

formatter.AUDITPATTERN.properties=pattern

formatter.AUDITPATTERN.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss} %s%e%n



formatter.PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter

formatter.PATTERN.properties=pattern

formatter.PATTERN.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n



formatter.COLOR-PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter

formatter.COLOR-PATTERN.properties=pattern

formatter.COLOR-PATTERN.pattern=%K{level}%d{HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n
```

With above config, server.log file still gets generated. But it includes only the first few hundred lines coming mainly from org.jboss and org.wildfly classes.

Any idea why server.log file is still generated on every startup?

Comment: Was the attached `logging.properties` used when the Docker image was built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out logging.properties coming inside the docker image was kicking in and producing the file until it was modified according to standalone.xml. Thanks to  [James R. Perkins'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152794/james-r-perkins) hint I was able to figure it out. Once I added a default logging.properties file with no file handler to the image, problem resolved.